# d3.js - blank object when applying y-axis scale

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to apply a scale to y-axis in my chart, but when I do it I get a blank svg object.
I did the same thing with the x-axis and it's working fine.

Problem happens when you uncomment this section

```
// .y(function(d) {
//     return yScale(d[1])
// })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MgwR5/1/

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `area` functions are `y0()` and `y1()`, not `y()`. Ref: [D3 API documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#wiki-area_y)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [js bin](http://jsbin.com/ugacud/623/edit).  I've put a bunch of comments in that should help and I've assumed that you wanted a line chart.

If you want to put axis's on your chart you should be looking to use the d3.svg.axis function.  It does most of the heavy lifting for you.  You also need to make space for the axis try using some padding and margins (you might want to look at [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245) or the example on the js bin d3 page - use the link at the top of the google groups d3 page). You also probably want to separate out your axis's and your plot by using svg's group ('g').

Cheers

Comment: Thank you I will analyze your examples. Actually I'm trying to make a horizon offset chart with multiple overlapping series